# Interface as the only parameter in the constructor - can this be made nicer / more efficient?

Tags: typescript

**Good evening!**

I am currently practicing/playing with TypeScript + WebPack

*( This is my first project. If you have any suggestions for improvement outside of the question, please let me know :) )*

I want to render some charts in a canvas. That works quite well already.
For this I created a class `Bar` (for a bar chart) and an interface `BarProperties`, which I pass in the constructor of the class `Bar`. I use this interface for a few settings.

Previously I had all attributes in the constructor and then given them a default value, but then it was inconvenient if I wanted to change only the last parameter, for example. (See **Before**-Code Snippet)

My "problem": I don't think that this is very nice - I can imagine that there is another way I don't know of to make this whole thing more efficient / clean, especially with the default values. (maybe even a library?)
Because before I had all attributes simply in the constructor, there I also gave the default value. So I saved about ~24 lines, and the whole thing was a bit cleaner.

I hope it has become clear what my "problem" is.

**Now**

```js
export interface BarProperties extends ChartProperties {
/**
 * The distance of the height (bottom and top) to the edge of the canvas
 * @default 0
 */
barMarginHeight?: number;

/**
 * The distance of the width (left and right) to the edge of the canvas
 * @default 0
 */
barMarginWidth?: number;

/**
 * The top and bottom distance between
 * the outline of the ProgressBar and the filled in
 * @default 5
 */
strokeMarginHeight?: number;

/**
 * The left and right distance between
 * the outline of the ProgressBar and the filled in
 * @default 5
 */
strokeMarginWidth?: number;

/**
 * The colors from this array are gradually used for the colors of the values of the bar.
 * If there are less colors in the array than values,
 * the next color is taken from the beginning again.
 * @default {../color.ts::colors}
 */
valueColors?: string[];

/**
 * This color is used for the border of the bar.
 * @default #34495e (light gray)
 */
strokeColor?: string;

/**
 * How often should the contour be drawn? (Or also: the thickness of the stroke)
 */
strokeIterations?: number;

/**
 * The font size of the font that serves as a percentage display above the chart.
 * Use FONT_DYNAMIC to have the font size calculated according to the total size of the chart (dynamic)
 * @default FONT_DYNAMIC
 */
fontSize?: number;

/**
 * The font family for the values
 * @default calibri
 */
fontFamily?: string;

/**
 * How much the text color should be darkened
 * @default .65
 */
fontColorFactor?: number;

/**
 * The font in the calculation by the factor {fontSizeFactor}
 * @default 1/8
 */
fontSizeFactor?: number;
}

export class Bar extends Chart {
  public barMarginHeight: number;
  public barMarginWidth: number;
  public strokeMarginHeight: number;
  public strokeMarginWidth: number;
  public valueColors: string[];
  public strokeColor: string;
  public strokeIterations: number;
  public fontSize: number;
  public fontFamily: string;
  public fontSizeFactor: number;
  public fontColorFactor: number;

  constructor(properties: BarProperties) {
    super(properties);

    this.barMarginHeight = properties.barMarginHeight ?? 0;
    this.barMarginWidth = properties.barMarginWidth ?? 0;
    this.strokeMarginHeight = properties.strokeMarginHeight ?? 5;
    this.strokeMarginWidth = properties.strokeMarginWidth ?? 5;

    /* Colors */
    this.valueColors = properties.valueColors ?? colors;
    this.strokeColor = properties.strokeColor ?? "#34495e";

    this.strokeIterations = properties.strokeIterations ?? 1;

    /* Font */
    this.fontSize = properties.fontSize ?? FONT_DYNAMIC;
    this.fontFamily = properties.fontFamily ?? "courier";
    this.fontSizeFactor = properties.fontSizeFactor ?? 1.8;
    this.fontColorFactor = properties.fontColorFactor ?? 0.65;
  }

    public init(): void {}
  
    public draw(values: number[], drawText: boolean = true, clear: boolean = true ): void {}
  
}
```

**Before:**

```js
export class Bar extends Chart {
constructor(
    public barMarginHeight: number = 0,
    public barMarginWidth: number = 0,
    public strokeMarginHeight: number = 5,
    public strokeMarginWidth: number = 5,
    public valueColors: string[] = [],
    public strokeColor: string = "",
    public strokeIterations: number = 1,
    public fontSize: number = 1,
    public fontFamily: string = "",
    public fontSizeFactor: number = 1,
    public fontColorFactor: number = 1
) {
    super();
}

public init(): void {}

public draw(
    values: number[],
    drawText: boolean = true,
    clear: boolean = true
): void {}
}
```

**Edit / Solution 1**

```js
export interface BarProperties extends ChartProperties {
  barMarginHeight?: number;
  barMarginWidth?: number;
  ...
  fontSizeFactor?: number;
}

const defaultBarProperties: BarProperties = {
  elementId: "",
  barMarginHeight: 0,
  barMarginWidth: 0,
  ...
  fontSizeFactor: 0.65,
};

export class Bar extends Chart {

  constructor(
    public properties: BarProperties
  ) {
    super(properties);
    this.properties = { ...defaultBarProperties, ...this.properties };
  }

  public init(): void {}

  public draw(
    values: number[],
    drawText: boolean = true,
    clear: boolean = true
  ): void {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a default properties constant and use the properties field on your class instead of each broken out?

```
const defaultProperties: BarProperties = {
  barMarginHeight: 0,
  barMarginWidth: 0,
  strokeMarginHeight: 5,
  strokeMarginWidth: 5,
  // Other defaults...
}

export class Bar extends Chart {
  constructor(public properties: BarProperties = {}) {
    super(properties);
    
    // use spread operator to overwrite properites passed in from the defaults
    properties = { ...defaultProperties, ...properties };
  }

  public init(): void { }

  public draw(values: number[], drawText: boolean = true, clear: boolean = true): void { }
}
```

But you have to access the properties on your class by calling `.property...`

```
const chart = new Bar();
chart.properties.barMarginHeight
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Then I'll do it like this for now!

Comment: However, you can actually still use your first class and use named parameters is you only want to change certain things. `new Bar(fontColorFactor: 2)`

Comment: Oh! I tried `parameter = value` all the time. Thanks for the clarification! But I will stick to the solution for now, because I can extend the interface (in this case I have default parameters, like `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`)